ASP.NET Core JsonResult for list of strings produces JSON with single quotes instead of double quotes
When serializing a list of strings using returning a JsonResult in ASP.NET Core 8, it produces an array of strings with single quotes instead of double quotes, as below.
['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
I'm expecting the JSON output to be as follows.
["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
As I understand, a JSON array of strings requires double quotes.  Because of this, I am unable to parse it with javascript/jQuery.
In my ASP.NET Core Controller, I use:
public async Task<JsonResult> RemotesearchGetPath(string id)
{
  var model = await formulaHelper.GetPathTree(id);

  return Json(model);
}

where model is of type List of strings
public async Task<List<string>> GetPathTree(string id)
{
  var treeId = ParseTreeId(id);

  return await GetPathTree(treeId);
}

In javascript, I have the following code, using console.log to see the json returned from the server:
function getFormulaSearchPath(id,callback) 
{
    var getFormulaSearchPathUrl = "@(Html.Raw(WebUtility.UrlDecode(Url.Action("RemotesearchGetPath", "Home"))))";
    var request = {
        DataSetId: "@(Model.Database.DatabaseId)",
        id: id};
        
    $.get(getFormulaSearchPathUrl, request, function (e) {
        console.log("getFormulaSearchPath", e)
        var paths = jQuery.parseJSON(e);
        console.log('paths', paths);
            if(callback)
            callback(e);
    });
}

Note that this javascript code is my Razor code so @(Model.Database.DatabaseId) is being translated.  I just noticed it's not actually being used as input parameter for the action method anymore, so could be dropped.
jQuery.parseJSON is unable to parse this JSON list of arrays with single quotes as it expects double quotes.
Is there any way to serialize a list of strings with double quotes instead?
EDIT:
I found that the result was actually serialized correctly, it was just the browser console that displayed the JSON object with single quotes.  Also, JSON.parse or jQuery.parseJSON doesn't actually work as I thought - it takes a string at converts it into a JSON object, it does not take a JSON object and convert it into an array of strings.
Sorry for that!

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

"When serializing a list of strings using returning a JsonResult in ASP.NET Core 8, it produces an array of strings with single quotes instead of double quotes"—how are you doing this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In ASP.NET Core, it's recommended to use IActionResult instead of JsonResult for more flexibility and consistency in returning various response types.
Additionally, ensure that your controller is inheriting from ControllerBase rather than Controller. This is important, as ControllerBase is specifically designed for APIs and provides a lighter, more focused set of functionalities.

Thanks, but since I'm actually returning a JsonResult, I see no reason to use IActionResult.  I am inheriting from ControllerBase.  As edited, I found the problem with my question,
